# How to properly edit git config file?

Tags: git, git-bash

My main code editor is VS Code. I don't have any Windows-based projects so I save all my work with line ending set to LF.

While adding my files to git staging area I got this message:

`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF`

I've checked documentation and similar questions and set `core.autocrlf` to `input` using this command: `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

My question is: is it Ok that inside my git settings file now I have both lines

`core.autocrlf=true` and `core.autocrlf=input` ?

Here is the whole file:

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.editor='C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' --wait
user.email=***
user.name=***
core.autocrlf=input
```

Is it Ok or I should delete that second line `autocrlf=true` ? It's a little bit confusing because I thought that mentioned above command will replace/update that second line inside settings.

Thank you

Edit:

here is `git config -l --show-origin` output:

```
$ git config -l --show-origin
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=openssl
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager
file:C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/gitconfig core.editor='C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' --wait
file:C:/Users/Wladyslaw/.gitconfig      user.email=***
file:C:/Users/Wladyslaw/.gitconfig      user.name=***
file:C:/Users/Wladyslaw/.gitconfig      core.autocrlf=input
```

Comment: Is it maybe because they come from different sources? Try
`git config -l --show-origin`

Comment: @WofWca Thank you for your reply. I've added output - looks like they do. Is it Ok, should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Have you seen http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/core-autocrlf-considered-half-assed-td4684075.html (in short don't use autocrlf say the main git devs!) Also please state your OS explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are 3 "levels" of git config – system, global and local](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).
As you can see, you've set `core.autocrlf` to `input` in the global config, and to `true` in your system config. In the end, for your user, global configuration of this var will take over the system one and it will be `input`. Unless you also set it in the local (repo-level) config.

And yes, it's a common practice.